# How can I insert a random element into a dictionary and have it randomised whenever I call it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, random

I'm writing a Facebook bot which will eventually produce a couple of randomly-generated statuses a day. Right now, I'm at the stage where I've got the logic of selecting bits of phrases from dictionary entries and I've written it so it will just work in the Python shell for the time being - the Facebook authentication stuff will come later.

Right now though, I thought it'd be cool to randomise certain nouns within the phrases contained in the dictionaries, and I was doing this with `random.choice()` and running a function that should return a new random element every time I generate a status. But the problem is that whenever I call the phrase, I can see that it's generated one random noun, but that noun gets 'fixed' for some reason such that the same random noun is reproduced every time. When I run the function as part of building a status, it seems to be working fine, but for some reason I can't figure, any new random nouns are not passed to the dictionary. Naturally, it works when I restart the program, but if I'm aiming to do this as a bot, I'd ideally like to not have to restart the program every time I want a new status.

I've done some investigating and I think the problem is not to do with my actual `random.choice()` stuff or the functions that they're in, but that the dictionary gets 'fixed' before my random noun function can touch it (e.g. the random choice function produces a random selection from the fruit list, but the dictionary will only ever have the same fruit selected when I run the StatusBuilder function). I have tried out some potential solutions with global variables and so on, but nothing has worked. The excerpt demonstrated in the code below is, I think, the closest I've come.

```
from random import randint
from random import choice
from textwrap import fill

def RandomFruit():
    return choice(["mango", "pomelo", "guava", "grapefruit", "watermelon"])

class DoTable():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

DoDict = {
    "do0": DoTable("sitting on the roof, completely naked, throwing Herb Alpert records at a dog like they were frisbees"),
    "do1": DoTable("eating a " + RandomFruit() + " like it's a handfruit"),
    "do2": DoTable("lurching around a supermarket"),
    }

class BeTable():
    def __init__(self, start_text, end_text):
        self.start_text = start_text
        self.end_text = end_text

BeDict = {
    "be0": BeTable("I guess ", " is what my life has come to."),
    "be1": BeTable("", ", just waiting for the police to arrive."),
    "be2": BeTable("If ", " is wrong, then I don't ever want to be right!"),
    }

def StatusBuilder():
#DoDict and BeDict will always have one entry selected from each, though
#BeDict will always have two attributes selected as part of the one entry.
    DoRNG = randint(0,len(DoDict)-1)
    BeRNG = randint(0,len(BeDict)-1)
#Logic to display concatenated strings
    status = BeDict["be" + str(BeRNG)].start_text + DoDict["do" + str(DoRNG)].text + BeDict["be" + str(BeRNG)].end_text
#print the status with textwrapping and with the first letter always capitalised.
    print fill((status[0].capitalize() + status[1:]), 80)
    print
    Controls()

def Controls():
    command = raw_input("([RETURN] FOR ANOTHER ROUND OF BULLSHIT, [Q] TO QUIT): ")
    if command.lower() == "q":
        quit()
    elif command.lower() == "":
        print
        RandomFruit()
        StatusBuilder()
    else: 
        print
        print fill("Some kind of wise guy are you? Try again, this time with a PROPER command please.", 80)
        print
        Controls()

#Start the program
print "PHILBOT V1.0"
print "A social media status generator."
print
command = raw_input("(PRESS [RETURN] TO GET STARTED): ")
print
RandomFruit()
StatusBuilder()
```

The sample dictionaries are included in the code above (which is a massively pared down version of the program which will run if you want to play with it). So the output I'm having trouble with would be the element in DoDict with the key "do1". So for example, say the StatusBuilder function picks the same phrases ("do1" and "be2") consecutively, what I want it to do is produce a different fruit every time when called with the StatusBuilder function, like this:

"If eating a mango like it's a handfruit is wrong, then I don't ever want to be right!"

"If eating a grapefruit like it's a handfruit is wrong, then I don't ever want to be right!"

Currently, whichever fruit is selected first 'sticks' permanently whenever I run it through StatusBuilder(), even though the RandomFruit() function seems to be working normally.

EDIT: I've now tried a few suggested alternatives (using lambdas and using generators) and have tried working with a simpler data format (lists without classes), but the problem is still being reproduced. SO, I'm starting to think it's more to do with my order of operations, as in the dictionary entry gets 'written' after the RandomFruit function is initially run (yay!), but it doesn't get 're-written' when I run it again (boo!)...this gives me a problem, since I can either declare the function then the dictionary (where the function doesn't seem to be speaking to the dictionary after it is first used), or declare the dictionary then the function (which doesn't work since the dictionary is then trying to rely on an as-yet-undeclared function). So, I think this is the root of the problem - any help?

Comment: can you provide an MCVE. showing us a sample dictionary and the expected output or outputs you want. my understanding now is that you want to randomize the values of the dictionary when you try to access them with a key is that right?

Comment: OK, good thinking, thanks - will edit the post.

Comment: And I should also say, the program already randomises the values of the dictionary as part of the StatusBuilder() function, but I'm wondering if I can also randomise the CONTENT of dictionary entries before they're called by StatusBuilder() to help make each status novel/different. I COULD just add in similar dictionary entries with different fruit names, but that doesn't feel Pythonic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.choice#random.choice) function as a value in your dictionary (I've simplified your example quite a bit):

```
import random
fruits = ["mango", "pomelo", "guava", "grapefruit", "watermelon"]
DoDict = {'do1': random.choice}
```

This way you get a random fruit every time you access the dictionary:

```
>>> for i in range(10): print DoDict['do1'](fruits)
guava
pomelo
watermelon
mango
watermelon
grapefruit
pomelo
watermelon
watermelon
watermelon
```

You could also use a **generator**:

```
def random_fruit():
    while True:
        yield random.choice(["mango", "pomelo", "guava", "grapefruit", "watermelon"])
DoDict = {'do1': random_fruit().next}
```

In this case you don't need to pass the list of fruits as a parameter:

```
>>> for i in range(10): print DoDict['do1']()
grapefruit
pomelo
pomelo
guava
grapefruit
pomelo
pomelo
pomelo
mango
guava
```

Comment: Am going to try both of these solutions soon as a I can, both look really promising so thankyou very much for that, will report back when I've had a go with them!

BUT, quick question first - is numpy absolutely essential here? I have absolutely no idea what numpy does, haven't used it before, so just wondering what it offers beyond the existing random.choice way of doing things...

Comment: Yes, numpy is not strictly necessary, you can use the random module instead (I've edited my answer accordingly).

Comment: Hmmm, tried both, and both seemed to reproduce the problem (i.e. it would randomly select a fruit for the first time the entry was called, but would then just keep that selection for all future instances)...I also tried reformatting the dictionaries into a more simple list and removed the classes to try and simplify things, and no luck. Starting to think it's more a problem with my order of operations - will edit my original post. Thanks for the great ideas though, good to learn new ways of doing things!

Comment: To clarify - it's not a problem with the alternatives you suggested (which all work, as you know from the examples you gave!), but how those alternatives can fit into my existing code...which may well suggest I need to change the structure of my existing code quite drastically...

Comment: The simplest workaround I came up with consist in replacing the call to `RandonFruit()` from the function `Controls()` by this code: `DoDict["do1"] = DoTable("eating a " + RandomFruit() + " like it's a handfruit")`

Comment: I've been playing with this workaround and I really like it - I've bundled a lot of phrases with random elements into a function which overwrites existing dictionary entries (as you suggest), and have created a separate ShuffleRandomElements function to bundle the different types of elements I'm working with together. So, it's all fairly tidy, and works great! I think the last step might be to find a way to automate the overwriting of dictionary entries, but I'll work on that later and call this answered for now. So thanks very much for all the help!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thank you for spotting this. I'm going to edit my answer accordingly.